# How do I change which direction I'm facing when swinging?

Tags: psychonauts

I'm climbing a wall in the first level of Psychonauts and can't figure out how to get Raz to turn around while hanging from a bar, so that I can jump to the one on the left.

[image: Screenshot]

This is a little embarassing, because I feel like I've tried everything:

- Left and right make me swing around on the bar.
- Up and down make me shimmy from end to end.
- Spacebar jumps off (in the wrong direction)
- Cancel lets go of the bar.

What button do I press to make Raz turn around and face the other direction?

Comment: THIS **Exact** thing happened to me too.

Comment: This question reminded me I bought this on a Steam sale and never played it. Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To switch direction, you press the **use key**. (I bound it to <kbd>W</kbd>, but the default is <kbd>F</kbd>.)

[image: Screenshot of Bindings menu]

(Equally embarrassing: I figured it out as soon as I posted the question.)

Comment: You mean you didn't try smashing keys before asking this question?  :D

Comment: But I'm glad you posted it! I got stuck at this exact part (which I think is an indication of poor game design).

Comment: @JasonAxelson The tutorial popup that tells you how to change direction on the bar appears just after you finish this section. They misplaced it by 1 area - It's just a mistake more so than "poor game design".